# CodeMirror onBlur event and console.log()

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

From what I've read about CodeMirror I should have `onBlur` written to my Console Log when I Blur the textarea. Nothing gets echo'd.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('block');
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
    lineNumbers: false,
    content: textarea.value,
    onBlur: function () {
        console.log("onBlur");
    }
});
```

Have I missed anything out at all?

Comment: For anyone surfing Stack Overflow for answers on legacy builds, the onBlur function within the CodeMirror instance shown above is the correct method for older versions of CodeMirror.  Newer versions use editor.on().

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bind it using `.on()` as described in [the CodeMirror's Events documentation](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events).

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('block');
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
    lineNumbers: false,
    content: textarea.value,
});
editor.on("blur", function(){
    console.log("onBlur");
});
```